# Want to collapse all rowGroups in datatable but only the first row is collapsed

Tags: datatables

I want to collapse all rowgroups of my datatables initially so I have added trigger action at the end of my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var collapsedGroups = {};
    var top = '';

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        pageLength: 10,
        order: [
            [2, 'asc'],
            [1, 'asc']
        ],
        rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: [2, 1],
            startRender: function(rows, group, level) {
                var all;

                if (level === 0) {
                    top = group;
                    all = group;
                } else {
                    // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                    if (!!collapsedGroups[top]) {
                        return;
                    }
                    all = top + group;
                }

                var collapsed = !!collapsedGroups[all];

                rows.nodes().each(function(r) {
                    r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
                });

                // Add category name to the <tr>. NOTE: Hardcoded colspan
                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append('<td colspan="8">' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
                    .attr('data-name', all)
                    .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr.dtrg-start', function() {
        var name = $(this).data('name');
        collapsedGroups[name] = !collapsedGroups[name];
        table.draw(false);

    });

    var rowGroups = $('.dtrg-start');
    for (var i = 0; i < rowGroups.length; i++) {
        $(rowGroups[i]).trigger('click');
    }

});
```

But i notice this only collapses the first rowgroup, even when it detects multiple groups e.g.

```
console.log(rowGroups.length)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note I have nested rowgroups: